# finding $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{(n+1)}{n})^{n^2}(z-2)^2 $ radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

find this power serie radius of convergence and  the area where it converges.
 $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{(n+1)}{n})^{n^2}(z-2)^2 $

my attempt: a) $L=lim sup|an|^\frac{1}{n}  \quad $$L=Lim sup(\frac{n+1}{n})^{\frac{n^2.1}{n}}$    = $Lim_n\to\infty sup(\frac{n+1}{n})^n=1$ $R=\frac{1}{L}$ therefore $R=1$ and for $|z-2|<1 $ it is convergent . is it correct?

Comment: I think you mean $(z-2)^n$; as written, the series diverges.  Also, the $n=0$ in the sum looks wrong.

Comment: It diverges except at $z=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2} (z-2)^n$$

then note that the coefficient behaves as $e^n$ as $n\to\infty$.  Thus, the series converges when $e |z-2| \lt 1$, because

$$\left [\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2} \right ]^{1/n} = e$$

Therefore, the values of $z$ for which the series converges is

$$|z-2|\lt \frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: n=0. so does it diverge except at z=2 as Doc commented?

Comment: +1 Possibly the $n=0$ term is OK if $(\text{expression})^0$ is interpreted as an empty product, equal to $1$.

Comment: @alex.jordan: yes, in fact, if you take logs, then that is right.  Then I do not understand how the series diverges outside of $z=2$.